# Correct term to describe how many % a portfolio consists of a certain stock?

Tags: finance

I'm looking for a simple word used to describe how many % a portfolio consists of a certain stock.

I.e. "The GOOGL shares takes up a large ____ of my portfolio."
Or "The ____ of the GOOGL shares in my portfolio is 30%"

What word should be filled in in those sentences?
Ratio? Portion? Proportion? Part?

Comment: "portion" sounds good to me. But I would say "GOOGL shares", not "share", to make it clear you mean shares of stock.

Comment: "weightage" is common.

Comment: @bagheera I wasn't able to find much on "weightage" but it lead me to simply "weight" which seems to be a correct term for what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: "Portion", "piece", "chunk" (informal), "fraction".

Comment: "The GOOGL shares take up a large percentage of my portfolio."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [part](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/part) :

> - A portion, division, piece, or segment of a whole.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=part%20of%20a%20portfolio&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpart%20of%20a%20portfolio%3B%2Cc0): 'part of a portfolio' is quite a common expression in finance.

It fits your first sentence ' Google shares represent a large part of my portfolio'

Your second sentence I' d rephrase as ' Google shares weight  is 30% of my total portfolio'.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Even rephrased and improved. +1